# Моя система подключения плагинов: есть ли автозагрузка, что я не учел и т.д

Tags: php

Решил написать, а позже учитывая комменты *@Alexander Zonov* переписать, самую простую систему подключения плагинов к файлу **index.php**:

```
<?php
class mainClass {
    public static $content;
    public static $added = [];
    public static function page() {
        self::$content = 'Init content';
    }
}
mainClass::page();

foreach(glob(__DIR__ . '/plugins/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $plugin) {
    if(file_exists($plugin . '/' . basename($plugin) . '.php')) {
        spl_autoload_register(function($plugin){
            include 'plugins/'.$plugin . '/' . basename($plugin) . '.php';
        });
        $pluginClass = basename($plugin);
        $pluginClass::page();
    }
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/tmpldir/maintemplate.php';
?>
```

Пример плагина например **plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php**:

```
<?php
class myplugin extends mainClass {
    public static function page() {
        mainClass::$content = 'Content overrided by myplugin';
        mainClass::$added['added_by_plugin'] = 'Text added by myplugin';
    }
}
?>
```

В шаблоне **tmpldir/maintemplate.php** данные соответственно вывожу через:

```
<?=mainClass::$content?>
<?=mainClass::$added['added_by_plugin']?>
```

Файлы на сайт может добавлять только админ сайта например когда устанавливает какой то плагин в папку **/plugins/**

**ВОПРОС:** действительно ли классы плагинов и их функции подгружаются в данном случае при запросе или на самом деле они все сразу выполняются и `spl_autoload_register` здесь не имеет смысла?

И вообще что можно в целом поправить, оптимизировать, что я не учёл и т.д. И почему люди используют более сложные схемы такие как Observer pattern или тем более система плагинов WordPress?

Comment: Не факт, что для обработки какого-то запроса нужны сразу все плагины, но инклюдятся они все.

Comment: я бы думал в сторону autoload.

Comment: PHP умеет автозагружать только классы. Плагины должны оформляться в виде классов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнём с того, что `spl_autoload_register` регистрирует обработчик автозагрузки. То есть, когда мы обращаемся к какому-то классу, описание которого ещё не загружено, выполняются обработчики автозагрузки, после чего ожидается, что класс таки будет определён. Таким образом регистрировать кучу обработчиков в цикле не надо, так как пути к файлам с определениями классов модулей у нас уже есть, то можно сразу их и подключать.

Далее. Часто модулями управляет админ через админку и в таком случае, подключать все модули из plugins не надо. Папка с модулями является только источником данных. Иными словами, админ отрывает страницу управления модулями, страница засасывает все доступные модули, админ отмечает галочками модули, которые хочет включить и для них создаются записи в базе данных. Теперь при загрузке сайта засасываются только модули, для которых существуют записи в бд.

Кроме того, модифицировать поля родительского класса не самая лучшая идея. Плагины могут оказывать влияние на самые разные аспекты работы приложения и хорошо бы это реализовывать через методы. Это позволит избежать глобальных переменных (с точки зрения потомков mainClass поля `$content` и `$added` глобальные).

```
<?php

interface IPlugin {

    // тут мы отдаём плагину ответственность за весь респонс,
    // но обычно имеет смысл давать доступ через какой-нибудь объект типа Контент или Сайт
    public function handleResponse($request, $response): array;

}

class Main implements IPlugin {

    public function handleResponse($request, $response): array {
        $response['body'] = $this->tpl(
            __DIR__ . '/tmpldir/main.phtml',
            ['content' => $response['body']]
        );

        return $response;
    }

    private function tpl($file, array $params = []) {
        extract($params);
        ob_start();
        require func_get_arg(0);

        return ob_get_clean();  
    }

}

class App {

    private $plugins = [];

    public function registerPlugins($pluginDir) {
        // хорошо бы подключать только плагины активированные в админке
        // и в указанном админом порядке
        foreach (glob($pluginDir. '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $pluginDir) {
            $name = basename($pluginDir);
            $fileName = $pluginDir . '/' . $name . '.php';
            if (is_readable($fileName)) {
                require_once $fileName; // подключаем сразу
                // если плагины могут быть загруженны с помощью автозагрузки,
                // то можно сразу инстанцировать их без require_once
                $this->addPlugin(new $name);
            }
        }

        // плагин Main -- особый случай, оне не лежит в plugins и его подключаем последним
        $this->addPlugin(new Main());
    }

    public function addPlugin(IPlugin $plugin) {
        $this->plugins[] = $plugin;
    }

    public function run($request) {
        $response = [
            'code' => 200,
            'headers' => [],
            'body' => '',
        ];
        foreach ($this->plugins as $plugin) {
            try {
                $response = $plugin->handleResponse($request, $response);
            } catch(Throwable $err) {
                $response = [
                    'code' => 500,
                    'headers' => [],
                    'body' => 'Всё тлен: ' . $err->getMessage(),
                ];
                break;
            }
        }

        $this->sendResponse($response);
    }

    private function sendResponse($response) {
        if ( ! headers_sent()) {
            http_response_code($response['code']);
            foreach ($response['headers'] as $name => $value) {
                if (is_string($name)) {
                    $header = $name.': '.$value;
                } else {
                    $header = $value;
                }
                header($header, true);
            }
        }

        echo $response['body'];
    }

}

$myApp = new App();
$myApp->registerPlugins(__DIR__ . '/plugins');
$myApp->run($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?? '/');
```

tmpldir/main.phtml

```
<h1>Site</h1>h1>

<div>
    <?= $content ?>
</div>
```

plugins/Plugin/Plugin.php

```
<?php

class Plugin implements IPlugin {

    public function handleResponse($request, $response): array {
        // если управлять не ответом, а каким-нибудь объектом контента
        // или сайта, то можно делать более интересные вещи
        $response['body'] = 'Content overrided by myplugin';
        $response['body'] .= 'Text added by myplugin';

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Иногда плагины взаимодействуют не только с сайтом и его содержимым, то и друг с другом. В таком случае нужны ещё более сложные системы, такие как в вордпресе или других CMS.

Comment: Егор спасибо! Допишите еще как в данном случае можно загружать плагины с помощью автозагрузки

Comment: Реализуйте автозагрузчик (вот тут есть примеры http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/)  или используйте готовый (из composer, например). Используйте нэймспэйсы для классов плагинов `namespace plugins\Plugin;` и просто инстанцируйте  `new \plugins\Plugin\Plugin();`. Файлы подключатся автоматически.

Comment: Егор, а если в двух словах: как именно плагины могут взаимодействовать между собой, например в моем случае когда они подключаются в цикле по очереди? Т.е. когда плагину который выше по очереди, нужен плагин который ниже и который пока не подключился. Кроме как инклюдить один внутри другого

Comment: @stckvrw У плагинов можно определить метод возвращающий идентификатор (имя и версию) и метод возвращающий зависимости. Тогда в процессе установки в админ-разделе надо будет разрулить зависимости. Ну а взаимодействие можно организовать на событиях: плагин сообщает что он делает, а зависимые плагины включаются в процесс (вы писали про observer). Зависит от задачи, можно по-всякому сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Все классы подключаются по очереди цикла, через `spl_autoload_register` в строке

`$refClass = new ReflectionClass($pluginClass);`

- БЕЗОПАСНОСТЬ. В `spl_autoload_register` я бы добавил проверку, только на цифры и латинские буквы, это ограничит возможный список подключаемых файлов.
- ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ. Не думаю что стоит вызывать все публичные статические методы, вызывай только один, например `plugin_init`
- ОТКЛЮЧЕНИЕ. Не хватает возможности отключать плагины, варианты:

  1. Если плагин заканчивается на `_` то не подключать его.
  2. Положить в каталог плагина файл `plugin.cfg` и читать сначала его, если в нем разрешена загрузка то подключать.
- ЗАВИСИМОСТИ. Для работы плагину могут потребоваться другие плагины, решение:

  1. Создать у класса плагина переменную со списком зависимостей, и читать сначала ее (загружая все что ему необходимо), и только потом вызывать метод(ы).
  2. Если есть файл `plugin.cfg` то зависимости можно указать в нем.
- УСТАНОВКА. Плагинам может потребоваться установка при первой загрузке (например создание таблиц, или загрузка в `locale/ru_RU/LC_MESSAGES/` перевода для русского языка, и тд).
- СОБЫТИЯ. Плагинам могут быть важны события происходящие в других плагинах. Поэтому все плагины должны опубликовать свой список событий, а другие должны иметь возможность подписаться на них.

Answer (score -1):

1. Популярные уязвимости в этой системе никак не рассмотрены. CSRF и XSS находятся вне её компетенции. От них эта система никак не защищает.
2. Если файлы в каталоге с плагинами можете добавить не только вы, разработчик,то это очевидная возможность для [ACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution).

Comment: 1. Это вы скажите. Вне её компетенции защита от CSRF и XSS, или нет? Если нет, то свои задачи система не выполняет.

Comment: 2. Можно загруженный пользователем файл добавлять. У вас в вопросе про это ни слова.

Comment: Нет, так не работает на этом сайте. Вы должны сами сначала попытаться что-то сделать, и только потом, если не получилось, просить помощи у сайта.

Comment: Если файлы, в не предназначенный для этого каталог, может добавить кто то другой, то это дыра.